# PHP run shell script can't write new files

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu, openpgp, gpg-signature

I know there exists some libraries, openPgp or gnupg, to encrypt and decrypt files in PHP, but it is a requirement of the company that the script works with bash script and runs from PHP like shell_exec("./myscriptencrypt")

```
#The example script:
#!/bin/bash
echo "$USER"
sudo gpg --output /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/outfiles/file.xls.gpg --encrypt --recipient myemail@myemail.com.mx /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/uploads/file_to_process.xls
```

When I run from terminal, this work very good, but when I run from PHP command gpg do not work and it doesn't create a file in folders, the folder have permissions: all users can RWX ->

```
chmod -R 777 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/outfiles/ 
chmod -R 777 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/uploads/
```

`echo "$USER"` print -> my current user name: usuario

**Extra:** 
I run on MacOS in local environment, but it will live in Ubuntu server.

Comment: Did you try to put the absolute path of `gpg` in the bash script?

Comment: like: /user/bin/gpg ?

Comment: @ThierryLeroux man the script work using usr/local/bin/gpg thanks! put the answer